# Taking the derivative of a sum

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to take the derivative of the following function:

$$\pi_I=\sum^m_{i=1}\frac{(p_i-c)}{n}\bigg(v-p_i(1+\gamma)+\frac{\gamma}{n}\bigg(\sum^m_{j=1}p_j+\sum^n_{k=m+1}p_k\bigg)\bigg)$$

with respect to $p_i$.

This is what I've got so far:

$$\frac{\partial\pi_I}{\partial p_i} = \bigg(v-2p_i(1+\gamma)+p_i\frac{\gamma}{n}+\frac{\gamma}{n}\bigg(\sum^m_{j=1}p_j+\sum^n_{k=m+1}p_k\bigg)\bigg) + c(-(1+\gamma)+\frac{\gamma}{n})$$

But I'm pretty sure this result isn't correct. Could anybody point where's my mistake?

Comment: In the first place, there is no variable called $p_i$. There are $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ instead. In your expression, $i$ is a dummy index, as are $j$ and $k$. You should clarify *which* of the $p_i$ you want to use (is it $p_1$? or $p_2$? or another?).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, MPW. Actually, I need to take the derivatives for all $p_i$. Considering the structure of the function, the derivatives are quite alike, aren't they? For example: $\frac{\partial\pi_I}{\partial p_1} = \frac{1}{n}(v-p_1(1+\gamma)+\frac{\gamma}{n}(\sum^m_{j=1}p_j+\sum^n_{k=m+1}p_k)+(p_1-c)(-(1+\gamma)+\frac{\gamma}{n}))$.

Comment: Why don't you merge the sums over $j$ and $k$ into one summation? Furthermore, you can (and need to) differentiate the quantity $p$ for index $j$ or $k$. This will give you a Kronecker delta, which will select one term when you perform summation.